# What is the most optimal way to work with database + javascript in terms of performance?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Context : I would prefer to work with Javascript with a database (pref mySQL) to create a new website.

I did a quick search, and one option would be to have PHP + JS + HTML.
However, isn't PHP kind of "old"/"slow" now ?

One other option would be to use Node.js (not really comfortable with it).

Any comments ? Is PHP + JS + HTML still viable?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should just go with a prop. Microsoft stack.

Comment: @true: why not Oracle+Sun then?

Comment: After I wrote the comment, Sun popped into my head.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is viable and it is widely used. Where did you get that PHP is kinda slow now? And what is the problem being old? Being old is more reliable and more useful as many users are contributing documentations and samples on how it's being used.

Slowness depends on your server's hardware specifications, your MySQL queries and code structure. I don't think that PHP will slow down your business needs because it's reliable and widely used by many companies. Being open source is a great advantage too.